# Ionic 5 - Angular: Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to call an api in ionic. i get following error in my console.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://apiresource.com/appservices/get_services' from origin
> 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Below is my code for API call

**services.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {NavController} from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-services',
  templateUrl: './services.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./services.page.scss'],
})
export class ServicesPage implements OnInit {
    services: any;
  constructor(private  http: HttpClient, private  navctrl: NavController) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
      this.http.get('https://apiresource.com/appservices/get_services').subscribe(data => {
          console.log('my data: ', data);
          alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      });

  }

}
```

**network_security_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">apiresource.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

**Config.xml**

```
   <platform name="android">
       <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
      </edit-config>
   ....................
```

I have tried on different solutions found from Google and above is all that i have in my code .
Please help

Comment: This error indicates something needs to change on the server side, not the client side.

Comment: This is one of the best and most completed samples in the question how to do it right. If you still have the error, perhaps a `https` page will solve the issue already, like it was in my case. I could change the domain.